# Why does the base of a literal affect its type?

Tags: c++, integer, literals

The decimal number *4294967295* is equal to hexadecimal *0xFFFFFFFF*, so I would expect a literal to have the same type regardless of what base it is expressed in, yet

```
std::is_same<decltype(0xFFFFFFFF), decltype(4294967295)>::value; //evaluates false
```

It appears that on my compiler `decltype(0xFFFFFFFF)` is `unsigned int`, while `decltype(4294967295)` is `signed long`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

hex literals and decimal literals types are determined differently from [lex.icon table 7](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.icon#tab:lex.type.integer.literal)

> The type of an integer literal is the first of the corresponding list in Table 7 in which its value can be represented.

when there is no suffix for decimal literal the types listed are in order:

> integer
>   long int
>   long long int

for hexidecimal the list in order are:

> int
>   unsigned int
>   long int
>   unsigned long int
>   long long int 
>   unsigned long long int

Why does this difference exist? Considering we also have this in C, we can look at the [C99 rationale document](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf) and it says:

> Unlike decimal constants, octal and hexadecimal constants too large to be ints are typed as
>   unsigned int if within range of that type, since it is more likely that they represent bit
>   patterns or masks, which are generally best treated as unsigned, rather than “real” numbers.

Comment: Interesting wonder why that is probably something to do with the most common usages but still

Comment: I never knew this until now and was having trouble finding this information myself. Thanks!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit C99 rationale added.